# Secure REST API with Amazon Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to secure a REST API using a similar approach as described in https://stormpath.com/blog/build-api-restify-stormpath, but with Amazon Cognito.

I want users to be able to sign up to my service, receive an API key and Secret and use those to be able to call my API in code. Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out how to provide users with a permanent API key and secret using Amazon Cognito. What I've found so far, are only approaches that need to sign the user in, receive key, secret and a session token, and when that session token expires, sign the user in again. What I would want is to authenticate the user through a permanent API key and secret. Is it possible to do this in Cognito, and if yes, how?

Comment: 36 hours is the maximum timeout for a cognito session token.

Comment: Any reason why you want to provide a permanent secret from Cognito?

Answer (score 1):

What is your use-case for creating a "permanent API Key and secret"?

If you need to grant programmatic access to your APIs, you may want to consider using API Gateway API Keys.

You could still use Cognito for the user sign-up/login flow, but you would need to implement a backend that creates API Keys for the authenticated user. You can do this using the API Gateway [control plane API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/usage-plan-keys/)

For an example of this idea, take a look at our [open-source developer portal](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-api-gateway-developer-portal).

Comment: So you would not recommend using Cognito for something like securing access to an api that is used by another application?  Could I safely say that Cognito is more for user authentication and I should use API keys for controlling access to call the api?